# Unable to register with external shuffle server. Failed to connect on standalone Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I followed the Dynamic allocation setup [configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation) however, getting the following error when starting the executors.

> ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 192.168.0.167: Unable to
>   create executor due to Unable to register with external shuffle server
>   due to : **Failed to connect to** /192.168.0.167:7337 20/03/25
>   13:49:01 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from
>   /192.168.0.167:55155 java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer    at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)

My Spark config on standalone cluster (local machine):

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("DynanicAlloc")\
    .config("spark.master","spark://localhost:7077")\
    .config("spark.ui.port", 8050)\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", 0)\
    .config('spark.rpc.message.maxSize','1024')\
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", True)\
    .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", True)\
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "1")\
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout", "120s")\
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout", "1s")\
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "512m")\
    .config("spark.rdd.compress", "true")\
    .config('spark.scheduler.mode','FAIR')\
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: From Spark side you need enable the following two properties

Comment: .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", True)\
.config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", True)\

Comment: from yarn-site.xml

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value>
</property>

Answer (score 0):

Remove configs related to `dynamicAllocation` and try. Standalone mode doesnot require those configs.

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("DynanicAlloc")\
    .config("spark.master","spark://localhost:7077")\
    .config("spark.ui.port", 8050)\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", 0)\
    .config('spark.rpc.message.maxSize','1024')\
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "512m")\
    .config("spark.rdd.compress", "true")\
    .config('spark.scheduler.mode','FAIR')\
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")\
    .getOrCreate()
```